# I am trying to access attribute which I passed but it's giving me a null pointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

In my **ImageUtility.jsp** where I display images in a table form after getting details from databse, I have an edit form(within **ImageUtility.jsp**) which will pass the id of Image to doGet() in ImageEdit.java, which after getting that attribute send it to **ImageEdit.jsp** and where I am trying to access that id attribute along with new name entered by user.

ImageUtility.jsp

```
        for (Images i : li) {
            id = i.getId() + "";
            name = i.getName();
            size = i.getSize() + " kb";
            preview = i.getImagePath();
            System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+size);
            pageContext.setAttribute("id", id);
            pageContext.setAttribute("name", name);
            pageContext.setAttribute("size", size);
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>${id}</td>
        <td class='ImgName'>${name}</td>
        <td>${size}</td>
        <td><img width='150px' height='150px' src='" + preview + "'></td>
        <td><form action="ImageEdit" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="id" value=${id} /><input type="submit" value="Edit"/></form></td>
        <td><form action="ImageDelete"><input type="hidden" value=${id} /><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form></td>
    </tr>
```

ImageEdit.java

```
@WebServlet("/ImageEdit")
public class ImageEdit extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
   
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int id=(int) request.getAttribute("id");
        System.out.println(id);
        //request.setAttribute(name, o);
        request.setAttribute("imageId", id);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("ImageEdit.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int imageId = (int) request.getAttribute("imageId");
//      int imageId  =  Integer.parseInt(str) ;
        String str = request.getParameter("name");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Images img = (Images) session.get(Images.class, imageId);
        img.setName(str);
        try {
            session.update(img);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            session.close();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("error");
            return  ;
        }
        session.close();
        response.sendRedirect("./ImageUtility.jsp");
    }

}
```

Imageedit.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="overlay"></div>
<form  method="post" action="ImageEdit" >
<fieldset>
<legend >Change Image Name</legend>
<label>Enter Name :  <Input name="name" required></label><br><br>

<input type="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on Edit button on here

```
<td><form action="ImageEdit" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="id" value=${id} /><input type="submit" value="Edit"/></form></td>
```

in ImageUtility.jsp I am passing in the id of Image that I want to delete to doGet() method but I a null pointer exception in doGet() method. I can't figure out what is causing that

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.package.ImageUtilityApp.controllers.ImageEdit.doGet(ImageEdit.java:23)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Did you tried getting id value like this : `request.getParameter("id")` ?

Comment: yes I just tried it  now doGet() is working i spent hour on this and it was a stupid mistake. But now when I submit the ImageEdit.jsp form i am getting .NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that form values for a 'GET' form get turned into query parameters instead of attributes.

Try changing your `doGet()` method from:

`int id=(int) request.getAttribute("id");`

to:

`int id=(int) request.getParameter("id");`

### Side Note

I'm fairly confident that you cannot cast a `String` to and `int` like that.

You'll most like need to do the following:

`int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));`

But, if that `id` value isn't passed in, you'll get a null pointer exception again, so you might need to do a null check first...  And then maybe some validation that the input value is a number...  etc...

Comment: yes I tried it and it worked and I had to do it as you stated in side sode , thank you very much for the help :P

Comment: but now I am getting NullPointerException in doPost()

Comment: You don't name your `id` in your 'POST' form, you only give the value.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you can you explain?

Comment: Change `<input type="hidden" value=${id} />` to `<input type="hidden" name="imageId" value=${id} />`

Comment: That was the delete form for which I haven't set the name , my ImageEdit form is in the question I posted and I am getting error for my doPost() in ImageEdit.java when I submit ImageEdit.jsp

Comment: I see...  I didn't read carefully enough.  But the answer is the same(ish), there are no submitted inputs for your form and you need to add something similar to the following `<input type="hidden" name="id" value=${id} />`.  You might consider opening a different question.